# select box, to url ( but direct to tab )

Tags: javascript, forms, element

Ok I have two pages:

Page A with ajax tabs
Page B with select menu

on page B in the select drop down box, I have:

```
<form name="mssgMenu">
            <div class="field2">

                        <select id="moreActions" name="moreActions" class="small" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">


                              <option selected="selected" value="">More Actions
                              <option value="">Inbox
                              <option value="">Sent Mail
                              <option value="">Compose new Message
                              <option value="pageA.php#tab4">bugMe

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

On Page A I have the tab ( lets say tab 4 referenced as )

```
<li><a href="#tab4"><span class="Mssg">HelloWorld</span></a></li>
```

So how do I get the select box, link to hyperlink and to open the tab ?page

Answer (score 0):

you can execute url and then on another page use parameter #tab2 with javascript to open it

```
function activateTab()
{
var params = document.location.toString().split('#');
if(params.length > 0)
{
    //code to activate tab
}
}
```

Comment: params[1] will be name of your tab

Comment: hmm, tabs currently work on Page A, however I want to open the TAB on page A from a link on Page B

Comment: for example pageA.html wil link to pageB.html#tab1 and code above put on pageB onload and append code for activation for example if you are using jQuery you can do this $('#'+param[1]).css('display',''); or something similar like document.getElementById(param[1]).style.display = '';

Comment: just reverse, from pageB.html to pageA.html#tab1

Comment: sounds good, but can you do a fiddle, I am not understanding fully

Comment: sorry, I don't have so much time, but u should try, basically what you need to do is for link 1 on pageb add #tab1 at the and on page a implement script which will be executed on load and then just activate tab from url

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQueryUI tabs, do these

On Page B change last option like this

```
<select id="moreActions" name="moreActions" class="small" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
    <option selected="selected" value="">More Actions</option>
    <option value="">Inbox</option>
    <option value="">Sent Mail</option>
    <option value="">Compose new Message</option>
    <option value="pageA.php?selected=tab4">bugMe</option>
</select>
```

And on Page A

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (getParameterByName("selected") == "tab4") {
        $("#MyTabs").tabs({
            selected: 3
        });
    }
});

function getParameterByName( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```